# Git p4 clone doesn't copy the files into git repo

Tags: git, perforce

I am trying to use `git p4 clone //dev` to get all the files that are in `p4 client` into `git` . 
But it is not copying all the files that are `p4 opened`

Ex:- `In p4 tree , I add a file called abc.txt` . But when I clone the p4 tree, I don't get the files that are opened into git repo.

Can anyone please help me .